# Emacs Erc. Typing password error

Tags: emacs

When I try IRC from Erc, I do:

1. M-x erc
2. Enter server - choose default
3. Enter port - choose default
4. Enter Nick - choose default
5. Then it offers to type password. I press enter -  and emacs shows `<return> is undefined`

My emacs is 24.3 and I got the same error both on Windows 7 and Debian.

Comment: How about trying two of the options defined in the `erc-mode-map` -- e.g., `erc-send-current-line`; and, `erc-input-action`?

Comment: Solved. Something was wrong with .emacs file.